# linked list insertion at beginning and at the end

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

At the time of insertion
Why double pointers are sent for insertion at the beginning and end only...

```
void append(Node** head_ref, int new_data)  //end
void push(Node** head_ref, int new_data)    //beginning
```

but not at the time of insertion in between some nodes

```
void insertAfter(Node* prev_node, int new_data)   //after some node
```

Comment: It's a way to emulate pass by reference in C. It's not needed in C++, since it have actual references.

Comment: if i'm using node* only then head always remains null...

Comment: please elaborate sir

Comment: As an exercise, try to implement your data structure with `append(Node* head_ref, int new_data)`. Pay close attention to the edge case where the list is empty. The double pointer allows you to skip this edge case neatly.

Comment: thanks a lot sir...when the list is empty then we'll be adding the first node and for that, we have to modify our head pointer...!!  am I right sir??